# Swift : Animate UItextField's width like the chat app when user start typing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, nslayoutconstraint

I want to animate the textfield to take the left button space when the user start typing,I tired to hide the button and change the constinet but nothing works

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIPopoverControllerDelegate {
    var chat = []


@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var textFieldWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var chatTableview: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var chatViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var chatView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var sendButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var cameraButton: UIButton!



func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: {

        self.chatViewHeight.constant = 300
        self.textFieldWidth.constant = 520
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.sendButton.hidden = true

        }, completion: nil)

}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {

        self.chatViewHeight.constant = 40
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }, completion: nil)
    self.sendButton.hidden = false
```

Comment: Did you set the delegate of the UITextField in the storyboard?

Comment: No only in the VC >   super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.delegate = self
        picker!.delegate=self

Comment: try it with story board as well and check if that works...

Comment: tried multiple times after setting the delegate in storyboard never worked

Comment: Are the methods "didBeginEditing" and "didEndEditing" being called?

Comment: textFieldDidBeginEditing and End are in the code above , I'm not sure what do you mean by called?